# encodeURIcomponent not replacing characters with correct encoding characters

Tags: javascript, percent-encoding

When I do:

```
encodeURIComponent('Cancún, Mexico');
```

It returns:

```
Canc%C3%BAn%2C%20Mexico
```

According to this:
http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

The character: `ú` should be `%FA` but instead its `%C3%BA` why is this and how do I fix this without having to do a lot of string replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> According to this: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php the character: ú should be %FA but instead its %C3%BA why is this and how do I fix this without having to do a lot of string replacement?

You should not need to fix anything at all. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding (and more relevant, to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986):

> the data should first be encoded as octets according to the UTF-8 character encoding, then only those octets […] should be percent-encoded.

So, `%C3%BA` is the perfectly correct encoding of `ú`, which is not a character from the unreserved ASCII range.

Comment: Thanks, do you know any reason why a server might return Ãº instead of ú when this is passed in the url as a parameter using encodeURIComponent?

Comment: Looks like the encoding in which he expects the URLs is misconfigured, but I don't know your server. It might as well be the response `Content-Type`…